# LINQDATASOURCE do not commit to database straight away

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Hi I'm using a LinqDataSource with a RadGrid. When I Add a new Grid item and click insert the values are immediately saved to the database.

Is there a way where they can be actually not put in the database until I give the command?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use DataSource control for that purpose. You can write your own in-memory datasource using DataTable or DataSet, then you can implement a command which you can execute on a button click to save in-memory data to actual database.